# jqgrid grouping with scrolled paging - stuck

Tags: scroll, paging, grouping, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a scenario where i need to use scrolled paging on my jqgrid, and it works perfectly. But now i need to add dynamic grouping capabilities to the grid as well. The problem I face, is that when I group the grid, only records in teh currently loaded page get grouped, and not the whole underlying dataset. Is there a way to acheive this using jqgrid.

a. Grouping groups all rows in a dataset, not just the ones loaded in a scrolled page in the grid. 
b. When expanding such a group and scrolling, the grouped rows now follow scrolled paging

Any help here would be appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for a while now with no luck :-(

Thanks
Lokesh